# In Azure Functions, using a Bash script, is it possible to access properties from the queue message trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Using Azure Functions, I'd like use the properties from a dequeued message as arguments in my Bash script.  Is this possible? And if so, how?  It seems documentation on Bash azure functions is a bit sparse.

I have looked at:

- [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#bind-to-custom-input-properties-in-a-binding-expression) on binding to custom input properties.  It gives C#/Javascript examples, but no bash samples.
- And this [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) with a similar Batch function.
  However, after trying to apply the similar concepts to my function, I've come up short.

Here is my setup:

### Functions.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inputMessage",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "some-queue",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

### Run.sh

```
echo "My name is $FirstName $LastName"
```

### Sample Queue Message

```
{ 
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe"
}
```

### Actual Result

```
My name is:
```

### What I'm hoping for

```
My name is: John Doe
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this, either by updating `Functions.json` or `Run.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bash queue trigger queue message returns as string and you need to parse JSON  yourself in run.sh. Note bash queue trigger is experimental. I think it's not easy to implement bash json parser as you can't install third party libs like `jq` in function app sandbox.

You can easily extract json objects from queue message using other languages (JS/C#/Powershell)